# JPA 2.1 criteria API: Using subselects in orderBy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Im trying to sort my query with the help of a subquery but always get a

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST
>   node

E.g.

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
     private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Item extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(name = "delivery_date")
    private DateTime deliveryDate;
}
```

I'd like to query all products and order the result by the earliest deliveryDate of its items. I build the query as follows:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> query = builder.createQuery(Product.class);
Root<Product> product = query.from(Product.class);

Subquery<DateTime> deliveryDateSQ = query.subquery(DateTime.class);
Root<Item> itemsFrom = deliveryDateSQ.from(Item.class);
deliveryDateSQ.select(
    criteriaBuilder.least(itemsFrom.get(Item_.deliveryDate)));
deliveryDateSQ.where(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(itemsFrom.get(Item_.product), product));

query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(deliveryDateSQ));

TypedQuery<Product> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(query);
```

When executing the query I always get following error:

```
antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: query
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1836) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderExprs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1627) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1603) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:642) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

And some more details from Spring:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query [...]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:216)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
```

Is there a way to change the query somehow to make it work as expected?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **@OrderBy(clause = "delivery_date ASC")** Hibernate clause.

so ur model can be like this.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {
     @OrderBy(clause = "delivery_date ASC")
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
     private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Item extends AbstractEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(name = "delivery_date")
    private DateTime deliveryDate;
}
```

Comment: But this orders only the items within the product. What I want to do is to order all products by the earlies delivery_date of their items.